# jScrollPane (jQuery) scrolling all items in a content pane API at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I need some help with something. I have 3 or 4 jScrollPanes on the same page, something like this creates them:

```
@foreach (var thing in Model.things)
{
    <div class="scrollPanes">
        <ul>
            <li>Model.Item</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
}
```

My CSS is like (these panes scroll horizontally):

```
.scrollPanes
{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

ul
{
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And here is how i initialize the jScrollPane

```
var settings = { hideFocus: true };
// Notice how all the elements with class "scrollPane" become a jscrollpane
var pane = $('.scrollPanes').jScrollPane(settings);
var api = pane.data('jsp');
api.reinitialise();
```

So this makes every  a scrollPane, and they all work perfectly fine as I'd expect them to.

What I WANT to do is scroll *ALL* of the elements by an equal increment using `jScrollPane().scrollToX(xxx);` or `jScrollPane().scrollByX(xxx);`

When I call the method:

`api.scrollByX(200); api.reinitialise();`

That works, but it only scrolls the first list, not any after.

I'm seeking to get it to scroll all of them equally, I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your original code didn't work is because of how the .data() method works. See http://api.jquery.com/data/: "Returns value at named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection..." When you call pane.data('jsp'), it's only returning the API for the first element in the collection (which is why only the first pane scrolls for you). To run a method on the API for every element in the collection, you'll need to loop through the elements one by one. You can do that by using .each()

```
$(".jpanes").each(function() {
    $(this).data("jsp").scrollByX(200);
});
```

Or, if you plan to call the APIs repeatedly, you can get an array of the APIs to call whenever you need and then use a for loop.

```
// Store an array of APIs for each element
var apis = $(".jpanes").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("jsp");
}).get();

// Call an API method for each element
for (var i = 0, api; api = apis[i]; i++) {
    api.scrollByX(200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had to accept your answer as it is the most correct and best one. Instead of creating all the api objects, I went with your first suggestion as it fit my needs better, and it worked perfect thanks. Much cleaner and probably more efficient too I'd imagine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add to each pane individual id

2) Write own function PanesMover(X) for changing all panes at once.
In the function move each pane on same X (recived as function argument), separetly by it's ID

3) Call in your document PanesMover(X), where X -is parameter of moving, which would be applied to all panes.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did, except I'm going to write my own answer too, as I haven't found ANYBODY talk about doing this anywhere else on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in simplified form, following Answer #1.

First, I attached unique IDs on all elements I wanted to scroll simultaneously, but they all use the same class.

```
@{ int paneID = 0; }
@foreach (var thing in Model.things)
{
     <div id="@paneID" class="jpanes">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     paneID++;
}
```

Then I initialized the panes with jScrollPane as before:

```
$('.jpanes').jScrollPane();
```

Then I initialized a separate jScrollPane API for each element's unique ID using an array, something like this:

```
var jspAPI = new Array();

$('.jpanes').each(function(index) {
    jspAPI[index] = $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).data('jsp');
}
```

That's it then, when I wanted to scroll them all I iterated through all in a loop

```
for (var i=0; i < jspAPI.length; i++) {
    jspAPI[i].scrollByX(10);
}
```

I'm surprised I couldn't find anybody who has wanted to do this before and asked for help, but hopefully this helps someone else.